# Find the expected value of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac1{\pi(r_2^2-r_1^2)}&,\text{ if }r_1^2\le x^2+y^2\le r_2^2 \\ 0 &, \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

I know that the events expressed by $X$ and $Y$ are dependent since values of $X$ restrict $Y$ and vice versa. Supposedly the covariance however is $0$. But why is it that $\operatorname{E}[X]=\operatorname{E}[Y]$?

Comment: The distribution is symmetric so $EX=EY=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are jointly uniform on an annulus centered at the origin with inner radius $r_1$ and outer radius $r_2$.  As such, the centroid of this region is the origin and $\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[Y]$.  The covariance is also zero because the density is rotationally invariant about the origin.  I leave the proof of these facts as an exercise.